# Проверка наличия COM порта

Tags: c#, .net

Как проверить подключён COM-порт или нет?
Например, пользователь выбрал COM 3, но во время работы этот порт был отключён.
Как грамотно выполнить проверку присутствует ли COM-порт и возможно ли его открыть?

На данный момент делаю вот так(пример):

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM 8");
string[] allport = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
bool stat = false;
for (int i = 0; i < allport.Length; i++)
{
    if (allport[i] == port.PortName)
    {
        stat = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (stat)
    port.Open();
else
    Console.WriteLine("{0} отключен.", port.PortName);
```

Но уверен, что данною операцию можно реализовать грамотней.

Comment: CreateFile вернет невалидный хэндл, если порта нет

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, порт может быть отключён в любой момент. Поэтому я бы делал так: работал с портом как обычно, а при приходе `IOException` говорил бы пользователю о проблемах при коммуникации с портом.

Проверять можно через

```
using System.IO.Ports;

var port = new SerialPort("COM99");
port.Open(); // бросает исключение, если порта нет
```

или

```
SerialPort.GetPortNames().Contains("COM99")
```

(как делаете это вы).

Но отлова исключений всё равно не избежать, т. к. порт может появиться или исчезнуть сразу после проверки.

Comment: а обработку делать стандартно через try/catch?

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Ага. Любое действие с внешним устройством может вызвать исключение, так что имеет смысл вынести try/catch на более внешний уровень.

Comment: благодарю за помощь и оперативность.

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло.

Answer (score 4):

Ваш код можно немного изменить используя метод [`Any(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx). Можно создать вот такой метод, который принимает имя порта, проверяет, содержится ли это имя в списке имен последовательных портов текущего компьютера, а затем уже попытаемся открыть порт:

```
static void OpenPort(string portName)
{
   if (SerialPort.GetPortNames().Any(x => x == portName))
   {
       // если такой порт есть, то попробуем открыть его и сделать что-то еще...
       var port = new SerialPort(portName);
       try
       {
          port.Open();
          // здесь может быть код еще...
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
          // что-то пошло не так и упало исключение... Выведем сообщение исключения
          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Port:'{0}' Error:'{1}'", portName, ex.Message));
       }
   }
}
```

А затем просто вызывать этот метод, передавая туда имя интересующего вас порта.

> Метод [`SerialPort.GetPortNames()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames(v=vs.110).aspx) - возвращает массив имен
>   последовательных портов для текущего компьютера.